# Runinng command on each line and export in the same way

Tags: bash, shell

I have multiple strings in a file, for each one I need to run a command and export the results. Here is an illustration:

**file.txt**

```
string1
string2
string3
```

I'm running:

```
while read in; do sigtool --hex-dump "$in"; done < file.txt > test.txt
```

This provides the following output:

```
737472696e6731a737472696e6732a737472696e6733
```

I would like the output to be separated by line like below:

```
737472696e6731
737472696e6732
737472696e6733
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: What happens when you run the code you have given?

Comment: This > `737472696e6731a737472696e6732a737472696e6733`, it will print in one line, with a space.

Comment: I'm sure this isn't the proper way of doing it but what about:
`while read in; do echo -e "$(sigtool --hex-dump "$in")\n"; done < file.txt > test.txt`?

Comment: Do you *have* to use `sigtool` for this? have you considered something like `perl -lpe '$_ = unpack("H*",$_)' file.txt` instead?

Comment: Note this won't be a standard format at all.  Have you considered using `xxd`, which can do conversions in either direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want newlines.  So output newlines.

```
while read in; do sigtool --hex-dump "$in"; echo; done < file.txt > test.txt
```

Note the added `echo` command.

Mind you, the first place I would check is the `sigtool` man page to see if there's an option to output trailing newlines.

---

Okay, I wrote the above without actually getting `sigtool` (from the `clamav` package) and testing it.  Now I have done so.

The code you wrote *doesn't work,* at least not with clamav-0.99.2-3.el6.x86_64.  `sigtool` accepts input *on its standard input.*  It has no option to accept and translate command line arguments.

So what you really want is, dropping back to the [old favorite non-visual editor `ex`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html):

```
printf '%s\n' 'g/^/.!tr -d \\n | sigtool --hex-dump' %p | ex file.txt > test.txt
```

Demonstration:

```
$ cat file.txt 
string1
string2
string3
$ printf '%s\n' 'g/^/.!tr -d \\n | sigtool --hex-dump' %p | ex file.txt > test.txt
$ cat test.txt 
737472696e6731
737472696e6732
737472696e6733
$
```

Explanation:

Globally (for each line matching regex `/^/`, which is every line) filter each line (`.!`) through the shell pipeline `tr -d \\n | sigtool --hex-dump`, then print (`p`) the entire buffer (`%`) to standard output, and don't save changes to `file.txt`.

---

Another approach, using Awk:

```
awk -v p='sigtool --hex-dump' '
  {printf "%s", $0 | p; close(p); printf "\n"}
' file.txt > test.txt
```

Comment: I suspect that will still unpack the newlines though (resulting in trailing `a` bytes visible in the OP's concatenated output)

Comment: @steeldriver, okay, okay.  I actually did the research this time and tested it.  :P

Comment: @Wildcard, great job! Exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative brute force:

```
cat test.txt | sigtool --hex-dump | sed 's/0a/\n/g' > gzout.hex
```

Just convert the hex newlines back as long as you are dealing with an ASCII text file.

(If you're dealing with non-ASCII you may have `0a` appearing in the hex dump without signifying a newline in the input.)